# Convert C array pointers to Rcpp with call by reference in R

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp

I have the following codes in C. I am new to Rcpp and I want to convert the C codes I have to Rcpp.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void calculate(const double *d, double *w, int col, int x) {
  int i,j; 
  for (i = 0; i < col; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++){
      w[j * col + i]++;
    } 
  } 
}

int main(){

    int i, col = 2, row = 6;
    int x = 5, y = 3, a = 0; 
    double d[] = {1.0, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2};
    double *w = (double*)calloc((row - a) * col * x, sizeof(double));


    for (i = 0; i < row - a; i++) {
        calculate(d + (i + a) * col, w + i * col * x, col, x);
    }

}
```

Rcpp code:

```
NumericVector calculate(NumericVector d, NumericVector w, int col, int x) {
  int i,j; 
  for (i = 0; i < col; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++){
      w[j * col + i]++;
    } 
  } 
  return w;
}

int i, col = 2, row = 6;
int x = 5, y = 3, a = 0; 
NumericVector w((row - a) * col * x);

for (i = 0; i < row - a; i++) {
    w = calculate(d + (i + a) * col, w + i * col * x, col, x);
}
```

This is my conversion that does not seem to work. My question is how to pass these parameters `d + (i + a) * col` and `w + i * col * x` as pointers in Rcpp, since its not an indexing?

Comment: You'd get more answers if you showed actual code rather than `....`

Comment: i just want an interpretation of `calculate(d + (i + a) * col, w + i * col * x);` with regard to pointer reference, because if i write this `w = calculate(d + (i + a) * col, w + i * col * x);` in Rcpp it is simply doing mathematical operation NOT pointer addressing.

Comment: Is `void calculate(const double *d, double *w, col, x)` supposed to be `void calculate(const double *d, double *w, int col, int x)` ?

Comment: calculate(const double *d, double *w, int col, int x) sorry about that

Comment: Perhaps you just need `d.begin()` to get the underlying pointer, if I understand correctly what you want. `d + (i+a) * col` will just create a new ` NumericVector`

Comment: You are not using `const double *d` in the function. also, why one is `void` and one returns `NumericValue`?

Comment: `row - a`... `(i + a) * col`... Would you mind showing me where in this code is `a` anything other than zero? Because you don't seem to be making any changes to it... Why add and subtract zero in an MCVE? Is that part of your problem? Surely not...

Comment: That code leaks. Also: it might be UB. You never check if you got a valid pointer from `calloc`, but you cast it anyway. `calloc` also does nothing to initialize floating-point numbers. That's not how floating-point numbers work. 
Please don't use dynamic memory management. 
C doesn't have array parameter types, sadly. They are interpreted as raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If the below line in your code works as intended,

```
NumericVector w((row - a) * col * x);
```

why not do the same in your `for` loop?

```
for (i = 0; i < row - a; i++) {
    NumericVector nvx(d + (i + a) * col);
    NumericVector nvy(w + i * col * x);
    w = calculate(nvx, nvy, col, x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to pass these parameters `d + (i + a) * col` and `w + i * col * x` as pointers in Rcpp, since its not an indexing?

You can use `numericVector.begin()` to get a pointer to the first element which you can then use. Here is an example

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <memory>    // unique_ptr
#include <algorithm> // fill
using namespace Rcpp;

void calculate(const double *d, double *w, int col, int x) {
  for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
      w[j * col + i]++;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void show_example(){
  /* Rcpp version */
  int const col = 2, 
            row = 6,
              x = 5, 
              // y = 3, never used?
              a = 0, 
          n_out = (row - a) * col * x;

  NumericVector w_rcpp(n_out);
  for(int i = 0; i < row - a; i++)
    calculate(nullptr /* never used? */, w_rcpp.begin() + i * col * x, col, x);

  /* old C++ version. (uses std::unique_ptr to take care of memory 
   * allocation) */
  std::unique_ptr<double[]> w_cpp(new double[n_out]);

  /* fill with zeros to get the same*/
  std::fill(w_cpp.get(), w_cpp.get() + n_out, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < row - a; ++i)
    calculate(nullptr /* never used? */, w_cpp.get() + i * col * x, col, x);

  /* Compare the result */
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Rcpp: " << w_rcpp << '\n' 
              << "Cpp:  ";
  for(int i = 0; i < n_out; ++i)
    Rcpp::Rcout << *(w_cpp.get() + i) << ' ';
  Rcpp::Rcout << '\n';
}

/*** R
show_example()
#R> Rcpp: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#R> Cpp:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
*/
```

Though, now you do not have any bound checks.